# delete 'nan' or reduce length of numpy array if array contains nan after converting to numpy from pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to delete `nan` from a numpy array. Lets say my numpy array contains:

```
np_array = ["123","pqr","123",nan,"avb", nan]
```

Expected output:

```
["123","pqr","123","avb"]
```

If we do it in pandas using `pandas.dropna()` it deletes the whole row which I don't want to do. I just want to delete the value and reduce the array size.

Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: These proposed duplicates only work for numerical arrays (so these are not really duplicates)!

Comment: I am assuming you would not like to delete the rows either?

Comment: Have you looked at pandas.fillna()?  In general, if a row is considered an observation, we would try to conserve the entire row and not only erase the nan values within the row.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `np.isnan` because the `NaN`s are strings in your array but you can use boolean indexing by comparing with the string: `"nan"`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np_array = np.array(["123","pqr","123",np.nan,"avb", np.nan])
>>> np_array[np_array != 'nan']
array(['1234', 'pqr', '123', 'avb'], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

Answer (score 1):

`isnan()` should do the trick. Working minimal example on how to do it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np_array = np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,4])
>>> np_array
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,   4.])
>>> np_array = np_array[~np.isnan(np_array)]
>>> np_array
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

Comment: does not work: 
error : *** TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs c
ting rule ''safe''
its dtype is object

Comment: Check the `dtype` of your array.  `isnan` raises that error for object arrays.   If there's no reason to have an object array, you can do `arr.dtype=np.float64` or whatever you want and then `isnan` will work.  If you do need objects, use MSeifert's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
np_clean = [x for x in np_array if str(x) != 'nan']
```

It will remove nan from your list

Answer (score 0):

This works for numerical arrays.

```
filter(lambda x: np.isfinite(x), np.array([1,2,3,np.nan]))

>>>[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```